# Finding the mean of r squared in a dictionary list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm running kmeans for a dataset with k=3. And also running linear regression for each seperate cluster and finding the r^2 for each one. So after i find the r^2 of cluster 1,2 and 3, i would like the find the mean of r^2 but not sure how to do it.

code:

``

np.random.seed(0)

df =

)
regr

plt.show()

Comment: Please post a minimal example. Are you basically asking how to find the mean of an array?

Comment: Well.... Do you want to find the relationship between 'Spending Score (1-100)' and the others for each cluster? Then, there is no need to split the data into train and test data. You just need apply k-means and regression using the samples in each cluster. Finally, do you want to make a 3-D regression graph for each cluster?

Comment: I just have my clusters in array so that i run linear regression and plot a 3-D graph for each one. What i am asking is how to find the r^2 of all the clusters.

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to find the average of the array then you can just do:

```
values = []

START = 1
FINISH = 10

for r in range(START, FINISH+1):
    values.append(r**2)

l_sum = 0
for v in values:
    l_sum += v

print("The array average is: ", (l_sum/len(values)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ages = np.random.randint(18, 65, size=1000)
income = np.random.randint(50000, 500000, size=1000)
spending = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=1000)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Age': ages, 'Annual Income (k$)': income, 'Spending Score (1-100)': spending})
```

df looks like

```
   Age  Annual Income (k$)  Spending Score (1-100)
0   45              271795                      40
1   48              185982                       9
2   55              312031                      29
3   37              463082                      95
4   62              337616                      94
5   62              142722                      47
6   25               53020                      63
7   63              115837                      71
8   36              173820                      42
9   57              496343                      58
. . . .
```

Then I'd create a column for cluster

```
df['cluster'] = y_kmeans
```

After that, loop through the unique cluster numbers, and get a subset of the dataframe to operate on.

Typically, if you want to evaluate a regression model, you compare the predictions based on X_test to the actual values in y_test.

```
cluster_regression_r2s = {}
for cluster in df['cluster'].unique():
    df_cluster = df.loc[df['cluster'] == cluster, :]
    X = df_cluster.iloc[:, :-1]
    y = df_cluster.iloc[:, -1]
    X_train, X_test, y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.4, random_state=0)
    regressor = LinearRegression()
    regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)    
    y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
    cluster_regression_r2s[cluster] = r2_score(y_test, y_pred)
```

Then you can calculate the mean of the r2 scores

```
mean_r2 = np.mean(cluster_regression_r2s.values())
```